# Handle press on volume button for certain time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, onkeyup

How can I handle press on volume button up for 5 seconds in this override function

```
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        val action = event!!.action
        return when (val keyCode = event.keyCode) {

            //handle press on volume up button
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> {
                true
            }

       
            else -> super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a delay on `ACTION_DOWN` and after the delay do your operation.

```
private var volumeUpJob : Job? = null
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.keyCode == KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        if (event.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (volumeUpJob?.isActive != true) {
                volumeUpJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
                    delay(5_000)
                    println("pressed for 5 sec")
                    // do your operation here
                    volumeUpJob?.cancel()
                }
            }
        } else {
            volumeUpJob?.cancel()
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
}
```

Note that you need to cancel the job when user pull their finger up of the button. and also when we caught the 5 seconds as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response, there is one problem that either when I hold for 5 seconds or just press on it, it will print the message "pressed for 5 sec"

Comment: Hmm.. it's kinda weird. Are you canceling the job in else condition? because that should cover this situation.

Comment: Yes I handle this situation.